# scikit classifier with unknown prediction

Tags: scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I'm planning to use Python Scikit to do some text classification, and was planning to use using TfidfVectorizer and MultinomialNB.

but I realized that MultinomialNB will always predict my sample into an existing (known) category.

for example, if I have:

```
category A: trained with sample "this is green"
category B: trained with sample "this is blue"
category C: trained with sample "this is red"
```

and I try to predict: `"this is yellow"`

it will give me `category A` (or any other, because the probablity is the same for all categories in this case).

my question is: is there a classifier that would give me "unknown" (or none, or false, or error) for the test case above?

I would like to know when my test case could not be predicted with the given training set.

I think I could check if `my_classifier.predict_proba(X_test))` returns an array with all equal or close values (in this example case: `[[ 0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333]]`).

actually, I would have to check if the values are close to their defaults, because the probabilities might not be the same for each category :)

so... any better approach or... is there a classifier with some confidence threshold I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into doing [novelty detection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html). I would check out that link and the associated [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html#example-svm-plot-oneclass-py). The idea, in that example, is to use a:

> One-class SVM is an unsupervised algorithm that learns a decision function for novelty detection: **classifying new data as similar or different to the training set.**

(Emphasis is mine.) I don't know how it would perform with the small amount of data in your example, I'd guess "poorly", but I believe that [novelty detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_detection) is the sort of thing you are looking for here.

Comment: hum... I'll do a test combining this with the current classifier. if the sample is considered outlier, I'll not submit it to the classifier. thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some unlabeled training data, you could add a *dustbin class* that contains all your unlabeled data. In your example this class would have the interpretation "not one of the colors green, blue or red". This approach is described in detail in http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03719

Comment: hum.. I thought about adding a 'fallback' class, but it is hard to anticipate what random text might show up. I would like a classifier that could say: "I do not have enough data to classify this input". Is there something like this?

Comment: I understand. If you don't have any idea at all what could be the possible input text, then the dustbin-class approach might indeed be difficult. To be honest, I have never tried to implement it myself, so I can't tell how effective it would be in such situations.